# Testing an isolated function of a component in React Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am fairly new to Jest and Enzyme and I stumbled a cross a problem:

I have a Component which renders Children and also calls a method of those children. I achieve that by using refs. I call these functions something like:

```
somefunction = () => {
   this.myReference.current.childFunction();
   this.doSomethingOther();
}
```

I now want to test the function *somefunction*. I want to check if the *doSomethingOther* function was called. Using a shallow render I cannot achieve that. The test would succeed if `this.myReference.current.childFunction();` wasn't called. Jest cannot know it because it only renders shallow and therefore throws an error.

I may be missing the full understanding. I wonder if someone has a Idea to test this function without using mount.

Comment: Won't mocking this.myReference solve your problem?

Comment: Refs don't work with shallow rendering. You would have to mock this.myReference somehow, like @ShubhamGupta says, to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the below code where I shallow render a component and then get the class instance and mock the required functions. Now when we call **somefunction**, we check if **doSomethingOther** has been called. (Assumption you are using jest+enzyme)

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Comp />);
const inst = wrapper.instance();
inst.myReference = {
    current: {
        childFunction: jest.fn()
    }
}
inst.doSomethingOther = jest.fn();
inst.somefunction();
expect(inst.doSomethingOther).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Instead of
```childFunction: jest.fn(); ``` 
you have to use 
```childFunction: jest.fn()**,** ```

Otherwise works fine, thaks!